# Is there a way to perform an insert into to SQL Server on a column that has IDENTITY enabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

I have a SQL Server I am needing to perform various update/insert queries to keep data in sync.  I am setting up a job as opposed to a cluster with replication or availability group for various reasons and just need a single table to sync. The destination server, along with the source has a column with IDENTITY enabled.  I am needing the INSERT INTO query to insert the 'ID' column, however am getting a permissions error on that particular column:

`The OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "server" could not INSERT INTO table "[server].[databse].[dbo].[Client]" because of column "ID". The user did not have permission to write to the column.`

I ran  `GRANT INSERT ON Client TO user` and verified I can perform insert queries to other columns in that table.  On the destination server I ran `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Client ON` as well.  At this point I don't think this is a permissions issue as the error indicates but not sure on what else to try.  If I run an export from SSMS and check the `Enable identity insert` I am able to sync the data.  Just looking for a way to perform this programmatically via stored proc.  Can someone advise what I am missing?

Comment: I think SQL Server only implements IDENTITY ALWAYS, but not IDENTITY BY DEFAULT. The only option I see is to temporarily disable the auto generation of IDs.

Comment: This is tricky. What you can do is: 1. INSERT data into a staging table that you create on the remote server 2. On *remote server*, run: SET IDENTITY_INSERT Client ON; insert into Client select * FROM staging_table; SET IDENTITY_INSERT Client OFF;

Comment: "I am setting up a job as opposed to a cluster with replication or availability group for various reasons" - and they are?  Often when you are fighting pre-canned functionality, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the target remote server in SQL server management studio (SMSS)

```
Use [databse] 
go 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Client ON 
go 


INSERT INTO Client (column1, column2, ..., column_identity)
VALUES (value1, value2, ..., value_identity);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Client OFF;
```

If you get a permission error, check the user mapping of the login performing the insert. It must have write permissions on the relevant database (catalog) [databse] This can be done in SMSS.

SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name ON statement should be followed by a SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name OFF statement when you're done, otherwise the IDENTITY property will continue to be disabled.

Comment: the problem is that you have to do set identity insert on the remote server

Comment: Use SMSS to connect to the remote server and test the query. Editing the post accordingly.